# Disabling CMake option has no effect

Tags: qt, cmake, cmakelists-options

I am preparing an application which should work with and without GUI, so I use in my CMakeLists.txt the command

```
option (NEED_GUI "Include Qt support"  OFF)
```

and

```
if (NEED_GUI)
  message("****GUI should be OFF****")
  add_subdirectory(QtGUI)   # The Qt-based graphics routines
endif (NEED_GUI)
```

Despite that I set the option OFF, I receive the message and the library is built. Where to look for an error?

Comment: Options are cached variables, so whatever you give is only an initial value (for more details see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)).

Comment: @Florian: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Your code looks good. So I'm assuming the problem here is that [`option()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/option.html) does transfer the value given into your `CMakeCache.txt` with the initial configuration step. After that you can only change it by modifying the cached entry for `NEED_GUI`. Changing the option in your `CMakeLists.txt` after you have generated your build environment will not update the cache anymore.

**References**

- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)
- [Advantages of using CMake option command rather than set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237287/advantages-of-using-cmake-option-command-rather-than-set)
- [How to tell whether CMake used initial value for an option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350560/how-to-tell-whether-cmake-used-initial-value-for-an-option)

Comment: I did not expect something similar caching, because I use the clean-all trick (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680420/looking-for-a-cmake-clean-command-to-clear-up-cmake-output), and I guessed it also cleaned cache.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (NEED_GUI MATCHES ON)
```

is the appropriate usage rather than

```
if (NEED_GUI)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it without option. Try to write this 
`set (NEED_GUI OFF)` 
instead of 
`option (NEED_GUI "Include Qt support"  OFF)`