# Can I cause a CMake internal error?

Tags: cmake, internal

Following my question [What can cause a CMake option not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744647/what-can-cause-a-cmake-option-not-work) I attempted to find out whether there is any difference between using clean-all.cmake and manually deleting the build directory. After running clean-all, I still experience the option problem. When I remove the build subdirectory, I receive the error message below:

```
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - not found
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:374 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:204 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:11 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:53 (include)
```

and the log file only contains:

```
Determining if files pthread.h exist failed with the following output:

Source:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>


int main(void){return 0;}
```

And, since that, the system keeps telling that error. So, it looks like there is a difference :) ; what is it? Is it possible that my CMakeLists.txt leads to some internal error?

PS: After having this permanent error, I started to look for its reason, building up my CMakeLists.txt again, starting with deleted build subdirectory.

At the beginning, I have

```
option (CLEAN_ALL "Make a cleanup before building"  OFF)
```

later

```
if(CLEAN_ALL)
include(cmake/clean-all.cmake)
endif(CLEAN_ALL)
```

and the cmake file is

```
# clean-all.cmake
# Cleans all subdirectories in the build subdirectory
set(cmake_generated ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeCache.txt
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake  
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Makefile
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles
# Above this, the common directories, below the project-specific ones                    
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/QtGUI
                    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test
)

foreach(file ${cmake_generated})

  if (EXISTS ${file})
     file(REMOVE_RECURSE ${file})
  endif()

endforeach(file)
```

It looks like the error is reproducible: deleting build and switching the option ON, I receive the error mentioned. At the same time, with option OFF, it builds OK. Is there anything harmful with using that clean-all?

Comment: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13714219/3440745) which is origin of your `clean-all.cmake` script **explicitely says**, that any CMake action after calling this script will not work. So, what do you want?

Comment: I think "will not work" and "leads to an internal error", are different. And also, in a second run, when the option is OFF, shall CMake remember that it was ON, until I manually delete build?

Comment: Values for options, like other cache variables, are stored in file `CMakeCache.txt`. If you delete this file, all stored option's values are lost.

Answer (score 0):

CMake stores the state of the project built as files in the build directory for the project. These files are *not protected*, so improper modification of them (like deleting) may cause state of the project to become non-consistent.

Message `Internal CMake error` means that this is (probably) *an error within CMake* **if project build files**, generated by CMake, **are not corrupted outside**.

Otherwise, such an error just signals that the project build is broken somehow.

In the given case, the inconsistent state is caused by deleting file `CMakeCache.txt` during CMake invocation. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714219/3440745) which is origin of your `clean- all.cmake` script **explicitly says** that after calling this script no CMake command will work.